# Run two tomcats on same machine with different JAVA path

Tags: java, tomcat, server

I have two applications, both needs to communicate with each other. `App1` is `java 8` app and `App2` is `java 6` app , both are web apps and App1 makes `rest` calls to App2. 
I want to simulate this on my local machine but not sure how to create separate `localhosts` for both the apps.

Please let me know if it is possible or not and if possible please help me in achieving this.

PS: I have installed both java 8 and java 6 on my system and using `jenv` to switch between java version.

Comment: Have a look at Waratek

Comment: @ScaryWombat: Thanks for your inputs but to start with, I want to achieve it using tomcat. I will definitely go through [Waratek](http://www.waratek.com/) usage as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, you can create `setenv.sh` or `setenv.bat` under `$CATALINA_BASE/bin/` directory. and set the env in `setenv.sh` or `setenv.bat`.

> when start tomcat, if there is `setenv` script, it will load this and execute.

**catalina.sh**

```
 # Ensure that any user defined CLASSPATH variables are not used on startup,
 # but allow them to be specified in setenv.sh, in rare case when it is needed.
 if [ -r "$CATALINA_BASE/bin/setenv.sh" ]; then
  . "$CATALINA_BASE/bin/setenv.sh"
 elif [ -r "$CATALINA_HOME/bin/setenv.sh" ]; then
  . "$CATALINA_HOME/bin/setenv.sh"
 fi
```

In Linux(`setenv.sh`), maybe it like:

```
export JAVA_HOME=my_java_version_home
```

In Windows(`setenv.bat`), maybe it like:

```
set JAVA_HOME=my_java_version_home
```

Comment: Thanks for this info. If I have understood it correctly then this will set JAVA_HOME for the running tomcat instance, but I want two tomcat Instances( or two localhosts) running, one on java8 and the other on java6. Please let me know if this can be acheived? Yes with your answer i can configure two tomcats with diff java versions but how do i make calls from one local host to another

Comment: @the_D, Why don't you use different web port, like `app1`  use **80**, and `app2` use **8080**. so your `app1` can connect `app2` by `localhost:8080`, and `app2` can connect `app1` by `localhost`.

Comment: thanks for you suggestion , i am accepting your answer because that gave me a startup and then your comment helped me in achieving what i wanted.... i followed the [crunchify](http://crunchify.com/how-to-run-multiple-tomcat-instances-on-one-server/) tutorial thereafter